# Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library to close excel

Tags: c#, .net

Having referenced:

Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library

in a C# project. Is it possible to close all open excel application on a computer? Thanks.

Comment: Just find the Excel process using System.Diagnostic namespace and Kill them. No need to use Office library.

Comment: Can you please provide an example as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Process[] processRunning = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process pr in processRunning)
{
    if (pr.ProcessName == "excel")
    {
       pr.Kill();
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot find System.Diagnostic dll in my .net 4 project. any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This namespace is part of System.dll and you already have reference to it. So just use 'Using System.Diagnostics;' in the code to import namespace.

Comment: Thanks. Please replace "pr.ProcessName == "excel"" with pr.ProcessName.Equals("EXCEL") == true.